# Portrait VC should be presented modaly on Landscape VC

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have a View Controller - A in Landscape Mode. 
On top of it, I would like to present a View Controller - C in Portrait mode. Bellow, it there is a navigation VC - B. 
For some reason, C is always landscape, even though I've added the following code:

[image]

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```